# dart pub global run webdev serve Building package executable... Failed to build webdev:webdev:

Tags: dart

```
C:\flutter\bin (stable)
λ dart pub global run webdev serve
Building package executable...
Failed to build webdev:webdev:
/C:/Users/valen/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dwds-12.1.1/lib/src/services/chrome_proxy_service.dart:540:24: Error: The method 'ChromeProxyService.getSourceReport' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'VmServiceInterface.getSourceReport'.
  Future<SourceReport> getSourceReport(String isolateId, List<String> reports,
                       ^
/C:/Users/valen/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vm_service-8.3.0/lib/src/vm_service.dart:846:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('getSourceReport').
  Future<SourceReport> getSourceReport(
                       ^
/C:/Users/valen/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dwds-12.1.1/lib/src/services/chrome_proxy_service.dart:540:24: Error: The method 'ChromeProxyService.getSourceReport' doesn't have the named parameter 'libraryFilters' of overridden method 'VmServiceInterface.getSourceReport'.
  Future<SourceReport> getSourceReport(String isolateId, List<String> reports,
                       ^
/C:/Users/valen/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vm_service-8.3.0/lib/src/vm_service.dart:846:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('getSourceReport').
  Future<SourceReport> getSourceReport(
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found `ChromeProxyService`'s implementation (`dwds-12.1.1`) doesn't match `vm_service-8.3.0`.

You can take a dirty fix as follows.

1. Open chrome_proxy_service.dart in your pub directory (`~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vm_service-8.3.0`)
2. At line 540, add the missing argument: `List<String> libraryFilters`

```
  @override
  Future<SourceReport> getSourceReport(String isolateId, List<String> reports,
      {String scriptId,
      int tokenPos,
      int endTokenPos,
      bool forceCompile,
      bool reportLines,
      List<String> libraryFilters}) async {
```

Answer (score -1):

remove `List<String> libraryFilters` and success